# JMH: Could not create SecurityManager: worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.BootstrapSecurityManager

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, benchmarking, jmh

I am trying to do API benchmarking using JMH. An error occurred during the initialization of VM: Not sure what can I do to fix this one. Could you please take a look at the below console output.

```
# JMH version: 1.21
# VM version: JDK 1.8.0_275, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 25.275-b01
# VM invoker: /Users/vbais/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.275.hs-adpt/jre/bin/java
# VM options: -Djava.security.manager=worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.BootstrapSecurityManager -Dorg.gradle.native=false -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=49776 -javaagent:build/tmp/expandedArchives/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.2.jar_56a88f9ce507637adfc797f83ef298ef/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=build/jacoco/test.exec,append=true,inclnolocationclasses=false,dumponexit=true,output=file,jmx=false -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=IN -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -ea
# Warmup: 5 iterations, 10 s each
# Measurement: 5 iterations, 10 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Average time, time/op
# Benchmark: ServiceCTest.extracted

# Run progress: 0.00% complete, ETA 00:03:20
# Fork: 1 of 2
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.InternalError: Could not create SecurityManager: worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.BootstrapSecurityManager
    at sun.misc.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:106)
    at sun.misc.Launcher.<clinit>(Launcher.java:54)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1444)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1429)

<forked VM failed with exit code 1>
<stdout last='20 lines'>
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.InternalError: Could not create SecurityManager: worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.BootstrapSecurityManager
    at sun.misc.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:106)
    at sun.misc.Launcher.<clinit>(Launcher.java:54)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1444)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1429)
```

The code which I am trying to benchmark:

```
@Test
public void trial() throws ParseException, InterruptedException, RunnerException {
    Application app = TestUtil.application(4,5,3);
    getOpsRest().postForObject(getInternalUrl() + "v1/Application", app,Application.class);
    Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
            .include(".*")
            .forks(2)
            .build();
    new Runner(opt).run();
}


@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@Benchmark
public void extracted() {
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(30);
    String lastEvaluateTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(ldt);
    ResponseEntity<OrgExpiryInfo[]> a = getRest().getForEntity
            (getUrl() + "/abc/'{lastEvaluateTime}'", OrgExpiryInfo[].class, lastEvaluateTime);
}
```

Comment: you need to show how you run that, because that is an explicit argument as seen in the output at the very beginning: `VM options: -Djava.security.manager=worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.BootstrapSecurityManager .... `

Comment: see [this](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4689) also. But anyway, from your code you are trying to benchmark some HTTP endpoints, `JMH` is for _micro_ benchmarks.